# Meaning of "Standort Vermittlung"

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

I have found a WWII photo of a palace in central Poland, in a city occupied by Nazis. There is a board on the wall with the following text:

> STANDORT 
> VERMITTLUNG 
> <CITY NAME>

Here's the photo:

[image: STANDORT VERMITTLUNG]

I have tried to find the meaning of "die Standortvermittlung" with no success. I couldn't figure out the meaning of the whole phrase from the meanings of "das Standort" and "der Vermittlung" either. I don't know, what the palace was used for by Germans but there are Wehrmacht soldiers on the photo I have, so I guess, it could have been military-related building.

Do you know, what does "die Standortvermittlung" mean?

Update: I have added the photo and changed the title.

Comment: Are you sure the photo was made in Poland? City name is Minsk, which is not in Poland but in Belarus.

Comment: @a_donda good link! Read the "20th century" part! Or you can even start with "Russian rule".

Comment: @Eller: yes, I am 100 % sure. The photo was taken in Mińsk Mazowiecki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mi%C5%84sk_Mazowiecki), thus "MINSK MAZ" on the board.

Comment: @Deoksyryboza oh, alright, it's another Minsk then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's "Standortvermittlung", meaning a [Telephone exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_exchange) serving a certain garrison. The term can be found in older telephone books as well as in [the "Zentrale Dienstvorschrift für die Bundeswehr" ZVD 64-10 dating from 1979](http://pingwins.ucoz.de/_ld/0/3_64_10.pdf) (the abbreviation is "StOvr:ni" - please don't ask what the "ni" means...). There's even [one Wikipedia page concerning barracks in Regensburg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prinz-Leopold-Kaserne_(Regensburg)), mentioning a "Standort-Vermittlung und Standort-Fernschreibstelle" (telephone exchange / teleprinter exchange).

Comment: I guess *StOvr:ni* is an artefact of digitalisation and the abbreviation is in fact *StOvr**m**i*.

Comment: Addendum: The document literally says on the first page (red paragraph): "Note by the firm Breuer-Computerpublishing: […] 2. All abbreviations were scanned and subsequently revised. However, there is the possibility that **abbreviations are reproduced incorrectly**." (*Hinweis der Fa. Breuer-Computerpublishing: […] 2. Alle Abkürzungen wurden eingescannt und anschließend manuell überarbeitet. Dennoch ist nicht auszuschließen, daß **Abkürzungen fehlerhaft wiedergegeben werden**.*) Hence, *vr:ni* is definitely a poorly recognised *vrmi*.

Answer (score 1):

These are, as has been suspected, really two words: It's the garrison (Standort) Minsk MAZ., and I suggest "Operator" for Vermittlung. Someone with more historical or military knowledge may have a better interpretation of "Vermittlung".

The concatenated term "Standortvermittlung" in modern day German would suggest a brokerage ("Vermittlung") for sites ("Standorte"), e.g. for real estate, construction work, with services like permits and administrative clearances, licenses, etc. But I suppose that term wasn't used in that context back in the day.

Presuming a military context, I can't categorically exclude a specific military connotation of the term "Standortvermittlung" that may have to do with what today is called human resource management. But I am not confident enough with military stuff to give a qualified answer to that part, and there is no entry for "Standortvermittlung" in [www.dwds.de](http://www.dwds.de).

That, I believe, leaves us with the first interpretation, an administrative entity for operations in the garrison of Minsk Maz., which, as we know now, lies in the heart of Poland.

Comment: *Garrison* beats *location* of another answer hands down. I see no convincing alternative to *telephone operator*, however, but I'm unsure, whether there could be sufficiently many telephones to require a full building. I can for certain exclude any brokerage type of activity - in military things are simply **ordered**.

Comment: You're probably right. I was thinking of switchboards, patch cables and grey mice all in a row and in long skirts. What a tease ...

Comment: ... and there's always the chance the building served other purposes that were not publicly shown or were accessible though different doorways. Just sayin' ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two indications that STANDORT (*der Standort*) and VERMITTLUNG (*die Vermittlung*) are two separate words:

- There is no hyphen that would combine them.
- The different letter sizes keep them separate.

Based on the context you gave, we can assume that *Vermittlung* is most likely a (telephone) operator station and that MINSK MAZ. refers to the Polish city [Mińsk Mazowiecki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mi%C5%84sk_Mazowiecki), which was occupied by the Germans in World War II. Thus, the board

> <sub>STANDORT</sub>
> VERMITTLUNG
> <sup>MINSK MAZ.</sup>

would read something like this in English:

> <sub>LOCATION</sub>
> OPERATOR STATION
> <sup>MINSK MAZ.</sup>